# How can I attach cabinets and shelves to an Insulating Concrete Form wall?

Tags: walls, mounting

So my house and garage have been built with [Insulating Concrete Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulating_concrete_form) ([Perform wall](http://www.performwall.com) to be exact) and I want to attach shelves and cabinets in my garage.  Pictures and other lighter stuff have been easy to do with some special plugs and standard picture hangers.  But I am unclear about how to attach heavy items.  There are no studs to attach to.

[image]

Anyone have some ideas on this?

Comment: So its just an outer shell that is filled with polystyrene/concrete mixture in the centre? I would have thought using longer screws and wall plugs. You might have to use a concrete drill and drill bit instead of the conventional masonry bits(which will burn out the bits when used on concrete)

Comment: The material is not like concrete, you could just press the drill bit through the material by hand easily.  It's kinda like drywall/paster.

Comment: All the way through the wall? From the inside too outside?

Comment: Well there is void, it looks like a cinder blockish item.  The material is pretty uniform.  But I bet with a long grill bit, I could with my cordless drill get all the way through.

Comment: OK - Never came across anything like that before. Not really sure what to say.

Answer (score 3):

For heavy loads you can use masonry screws (Tapcon).  It is imperative that you drill to the proper depth and clear the dust from the drill hole.  I highly recommend the hex head Tapcon over the Phillips.

ICF usually has these layers from inside to out:
1. Drywall
2. ICF polystyrene foam form with composite anchor strips at 8" centers for drywall and lightweight mounting
3. Concrete wall
4. ICF polystyrene foam form with composite anchor strips at 8" centers for stucco lath and lightweight mounting
5. Stucco

The strips can be used for light mounts using multiple anchor points but loads should anchor to concrete.  You will have to know the depth from your anchor point to the concrete and then add at least 1" to drill and embed the Tapcon.  In my application: 1/2" drywall + 3" foam = 3 1/2" to concrete + 1 1/2" Tapcon embed = 5" Tapcon using 6" Tapcon drill bit on cordless hammer drill.

Again it is imperative to clear the borehole of concrete dust or you will snap the head off the anchor.  If you do it right these anchors have 10X the load capacity of studs.